# Lazy Instantiation of UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, lazy-initialization

I have a WPF application that I am trying to switch the contents of a window efficiently. I have come up with the solution of the following:

**App.cs**

```
internal static Lazy<HomeUserControl> HomePage;
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = App.HomePage;

   }
```

**HomeUserControl.cs**

```
public HomeUserControl()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
```

I am running into a problem that `MainWindow.Content` is basically being set to a blank window (it is actually changing the content of `MainWindow`). If I use `App.MainWindow.Content = new HomePageUserControl()`, everything works as it should. However, I would like to keep one instance of the page, which is why I made a static one in the App class. This problem occurs whether `Lazy<>` is used or not. I have tried a check to see if `HomePage` was `null`, and I got back a label that said `Value is not created.`, which I'm pretty sure is the representation of an uninitialized `Lazy<>`; however, this only occurs if I check `App.HomePage == null`. Any ideas?

Comment: **XY problem**. You shouldn't need this. UI elements' load time is really not perceivable unless you have thousands of UI elements OR put data or business logic in the UI where it does not belong.

Comment: @HighCore Hmm. If you're talking about lazily instantiating the pages, I was wondering about that too, but ended up doing that since it seemed like it would be a performance increase even if minimal. Should I just instantiate them like normal since I don't have a ton of pages at the moment?

Comment: yes, i'd rather go the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = App.HomePage.Value;
```